# Exponential family where set of natural parameters has empty interior

Tags: self-study, exponential-family, umvue

In my math-stat class we have a theorem that goes:

Let $\{P_\theta : \theta \in \Theta\}$ be a $k$ parameter exponential family (i.e. the density of a member of this family can be written as $f(\mathbf{x}) = h(\mathbf{x})e^{\sum_{i=1}^k c_i(\theta)T_i(\mathbf{x}) - B(\theta)}$), suppose $\{c_1(\theta),\ldots,c_k(\theta)\}$ (what I am calling the natural parameters) has a **non-empty** interior. Then $T(\mathbf{X}) = \{(T_1(\mathbf{X}),\ldots, T_k(\mathbf{X})\}$ is complete and sufficient.

This theorem is often used to identify UMVUE (Uniform minimum variance unbiased estimators) using the Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem.

I haven't run into any good examples of an exponential family where the set of natural parameters has an empty interior, can you guys provide a good example?

Comment: One class of examples are called *curved exponential families*. I would be surprised if your book (or course notes) does not make any mention of them or  give at least one example. The classic example is a normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\mu^2$.